# Python pandas read_csv with custom separator

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file where columns are separated using a non-standard symbol (||/).

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_analyst_assignment.csv',sep='||/', engine='python')
```

This throws an error:

> ParserError: Expected 61 fields in line 3, saw 68. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Can you please help me how to read this file?

Comment: No knowing even data structure, how one can diagnose the problem?

Comment: Try `\|\|/` and tell us (escape pipe)

Comment: looks like you have 61 columns, but in line 3 you have 68 values. If you could share a sample dataset, that would be helpful to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you azro it worked! So, @ipj you do not need the know the data structure, huh?

Comment: I've set down an answer so ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

> **sep**:str, default ‘,’ :  Delimiter to use. ... In addition, separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be interpreted as **regular expressions** and will also force the use of the Python parsing engine.

And `|` is special char in regex grammar (means OR) so you need to escape it, so you need

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_analyst_assignment.csv',sep='\|\|/', engine='python')
```